# Анализ видео или снимков с веб камеры в реальном времени

Tags: c#

Поставлена задача: ловить движение некоторого объекта на видео (или снимках) с веб камеры и анализировать это движение. Даже не знаю как подступиться к задаче. Веб-камера c USB интерфейсом.Предполагается, что объект на изображении будет достаточно контрастным. Подходы, фреймворки, алгоритмы, любая информация полезна.
Примечание: анализируемый объект - не человеческое лицо))

Comment: Скорее всего, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону OpenCV. У них есть [байндинг к .NET](http://friism.com/webcam-face-detection-in-c-using-emgu-cv).

Comment: тоже об этом думал, гуглил

Answer (score 2):

> ловить движение некоторого объекта на видео (или снимках) с веб
>   камеры и анализировать это движение

Трекинг объектов - это очень сложная задача (если в общем виде, конечно же). Можете описать конкретно ваш случай?
Но однозначно вам нужен EmguCV и, возможно, какие-нибудь библиотеки машинного обучения. 
В простейшем случае, если объект хорошо отличим от фона и условия съемки не меняются, то можно использовать Canny edge detector из пакета opencv(emgucv для C#). А анализ движения - это уже отдельная тема, все зависит именно от вашей задачи, но здесь, наверняка, пригодятся алгоритмы машинного обучения.

Answer (score 0):

1. Научись получать изображение с камеры.
2. Научись определять нужный объект на снимке.
   Для этого можно использовать отклонение среднего цвета по области или выделение наиболее близкого к искомому цвета.
3. Сравни координаты между соседними ссылками.

> это понятно, было интересно узнать как это делается

Как пример. Берём картинку, экспериментально определяем размер квадрата для следующих целей. Вокруг каждого пикселя берём квадрат с центром в нём и считаем среднее арифметическое по каждой компоненте цвета. Сравниваем это значение по всем пикселям и наиболее выделяющийся рассматриваем как искомый.

> на мой взгляд дилетанта, процессор будет грузиться просто страшно, а ведь желательно делать это еще и в реальном времени, ну или на худой конец по 10 кадров в секунду.

Описанное мной делается за линейное отноистельно площади время (если точнее, то за 2 прохода по 3-4 обращения в каждом). Насколько реально сделать болеее рационально? Ну не знаю, мне кажется, ассимптотика очень даже ничего.

Если надо быстрее, то, возможно, стоит рыть в сторону распараллеливания и вычислений на видеокарте. Вероятно, там уже что-то другое надо будет использовать, потому что мой вариант с двумя проходами распараллеливается плохо. Хотя, может там можно будет тупо считать квадраты, а не делать предподсчёт - не знаю.

Comment: это понятно, было интересно узнать как это делается

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov, написал подробнее.

Comment: на мой взгляд дилетанта, процессор будет грузиться просто страшно, а ведь желательно делать это еще и в реальном времени, ну или на худой конец по 10 кадров в секунду. Фон и объект будут контрастными, а значит можно провести байнаризацию

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov, дополнил ответ про скорость. Но, конечно, всё будет зависеть от разрешения и числа кадров в секунду.